# Installing OS packages in airflow container

Tags: airflow

I have a **containerized** airflow instance on my local machine. I'm trying to use `wget` via the `BashOperator` to download a file, but I get the error command not found. Task code:

```
     download = BashOperator(task_id='download_file',
                             # --- `/usr/local/bin/wget {url}` does not work either.
                             bash_command=f'wget {url}')
```

I think this is because the bash code is running on the airflow container rather than
my local machine. Is there a way to configure this via `docker-compose.yml` of the airflow?

Answer (score 1):

wget is not installed on the airflow worker that runs the bash operator.

- You can create a Dockerfile base on apache/airflow and install wget on the worker. change the airflow-worker build from your dockerfile.
- or use PythonOperator with existing modules that you don't need to install

> ```
> import urllib.request
> from airflow.decorators import task
>
> @task
> def download_file(uri, target_path):
>     with urllib.request.urlopen(uri) as file:
>         with open(target_path, "wt") as new_file:
>             new_file.write(file.read())
> ```